# How Dalet, Final Kaf, Vav, Final Nun, and Resh (and maybe Yod) are differentiated in print

Tags: writing-system, hebrew

When either handwritten notes or computer printed documents are read, these letters have a very similar structure `ד ך ו‬ ן ר`. I guess you could say it is just as similar as `ij` or `il` or `tf`, even `qg`. When writing though it seems it would be difficult to differentiate, but maybe you can easily tell by adding into the mix the meaning of the content and the probably next word, so maybe it's a non-issue. I have this same thought with seeing Chinese characters in which slight curve variations totally change meaning. I would like to know though if, when kids are learning Hebrew, they get some sort of special lessons on these letters so they can distinguish them.

Comment: No, they look different enough. It's not a real issue. And when writing them by hand, in cursive, they look even more different. Its just like the Latin alphabet examples you gave; simple exposure is the fix.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that writing manually is usually in cursive, I did not know that.

Comment: Here are two good videos of hebrew handwriting: 1.) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oS-quxkdSzc and 2.) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTzyRdoXlbs

Comment: You may also put zayin on the list